# Calculation for the distance between maximum swings in the drift distance of electrons

Tags: voltage, ac, electron

I am currently studying the textbook *Practical Electronics for Inventors, Fourth Edition*, by Scherz and Monk. In section **2.4.1 Applying a Voltage**, the authors have written the following:

> In the case of alternating current, the field reverses directions in a sinusoidal fashion, causing the drift velocity component of electrons to swish back and forth. If the alternating current has a frequency of 60 Hz, the velocity component would be vibrating back and forth 60 times a second. If our maximum drift velocity during an ac cycle is 0.002 mm/s, we could roughly determine that the distance between maximum swings in the drift distance would be about 0.00045 mm. Of course, this doesn’t mean that electrons are fixed in an oscillatory position. It means only that the drift displacement component of electrons is — if there is such a notion. Recall that an electron’s overall motion is quite random and its actual displacement quite large, due to the thermal effects.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

I'm wondering how the authors concluded that the distance between maximum swings in the drift distance would be about 0.00045 mm? What is the calculation that was done here?

I would appreciate it if someone would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: The information you have provided in your question is not sufficient to verify those results, in order to calculate the drift velocity in a wire you need to know the current in the wire, the diameter of the wire and the material of the wire, as the drift velocity is determined by the current in the wire in amps and the number of free electrons in the wire per length unit, which can be calculated if you know the diameter of the wire and the material. All these are parameters that you have not given in your question or in the picture.

Comment: @Vinzent My apologies for any confusion. As I said, it isn't clear how the authors calculated that value, so I didn't realise that I would need to include the information from the diagram on a previous page. I have now edited my post.

Comment: @ThePointer You can see some thoughts [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/411784/38098). Just FYI. Not an answer.

Comment: According to my calculations for 0.002 mm/s maximum velocity at 60Hz the amplitude should be 0.002 / 2pi*60 = 0.0000053mm. I have no idea how they got a value 85 times higher.

Comment: @jonk Thanks for that. Can the calculation you used to find $$\frac{1\:\text{A}}{1.3476\times 10^{4}\:\frac{\text{Coulomb}}{\text{cc}}\:\cdot\: 0.51887\: \text{mm}^2}\approx 143 \:\frac{\mu m}{s}$$ also be used to find the distance between maximum swings? If so, then what is the calculation to find the cross-section of the copper wire, as you did in your answer to that question?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Hmm, that's strange. So the general formula to find the distance between maximum swings is $$\dfrac{\text{maximum drift velocity}}{2\pi \times \text{AC frequency}} = \text{distance between maximum swings}$$? And you're sure that all of the units are correct? It could be an error on the authors' part.

Comment: I used the formula for [Simple Harmonic Motion](http://physicsnet.co.uk/a-level-physics-as-a2/further-mechanics/simple-harmonic-motion-shm/). I suppose it's possible that electron drift in a wire don't follow this, but the only example I could find used the same formula that I did.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I figured it out (see my answer).

Comment: @jonk In an unrelated comment, how does one format mathematics inline on this website (using single $ on either side instead of $$ on either side)?

Comment: Use \$ for inline mathjax https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/most-common-mathjax-uses-in-electrical-engineering (they want us to use mathjax, but this is all the help they give us...)

Comment: @BruceAbbott Ahh, thanks for that!

Comment: @ThePointer I'm glad Bruce got you to an answer. It's worth learning. If you have ever used Latex, it's like a "some stuff removed to make it safer" version. You can use the simpler portions of Latex with some confidence.

Comment: @BruceAbbott User Philip Wood from physics.stackexchange just answered that he thinks that your answer is the correct one physics.stackexchange.com/a/523322/141502

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that displacement \$d\$ is the area under the velocity curve. For a sinusoidal drift velocity \$v_d\$ having radian frequency \$\omega=2\pi f\$ where \$f=60\,\text{Hz}\$, the magnitude of maximum displacement over one half cycle can be calculated as the integral of \$v_d\$ with respect to time, during the time interval \$(0 \le t \le \pi/\omega)\,\text{s}\$:

$$
\begin{align*}
d &= \int_{0}^{\pi/\omega}v_d\,dt,\;\;v_d(t) = J(t) / (\rho_e\,e)\\
&= \frac{1}{\rho_e\,e}\int_{0}^{\pi/\omega}J(t)\,dt,\;\;J(t) = I(t)/A\\
&= \frac{1}{\rho_e\,e\,A}\int_{0}^{\pi/\omega}I(t)\,dt,\;\;I(t) = k\,\sin (\omega t)\\
&= \frac{k}{\rho_e\,e\,A}\int_{0}^{\pi/\omega}\sin(\omega t)\,dt\\
&= \frac{2\,k}{\rho_e\,e\,A\,\omega}
\end{align*}
$$

where \$k=0.1\,\text{A}\$ (as specified in the book example).

For what it's worth, when I crunch the numbers with MATLAB (see Listing 1 and Figure 1 below) the calculated displacement—i.e., drift distance—is approximately 12 nm; so I'm not sure how the authors arrived at the value 450 nm for the drift distance.

See also:

- http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/ohmmic.html
- https://activecalculus.org/single/sec-4-1-velocity-distance.html
- https://pages.uncc.edu/phys2102/online-lectures/chapter-6-electric-current-and-resistance/6-3-drift-speed/

---

Listing 1.  MATLAB source code

```matlab
%% Housekeeping
clc
clear

%% Givens
d = 2.05e-3;            % wire diameter, m
r = d/2;                % wire radius, m
A = pi*(r^2);           % wire cross-sectional area, m^2

q = 1.602e-19;          % electron charage, C
                        % (NB: This is 'e' in the equation above).

n = 8.46e28;            % estimate of the number of charge-conducting 
                        % electrons per cubic meter in solid copper
                        % (NB: This is 'rho_e' in the equation above).

k = 0.1;                % Sinusoidal current amplitude, peak
f = 60;                 % Sinusoidal current frequency, Hz
w = 2 * pi * f;         % Sinusoidal current frequency, rad/sec

%% Equations
% Current in the wire, C/s
I = @(t)  k * sin(w*t);

% Current density in the wire at time t, C s^-1 m^-2
% J = I/A = k*sin(w*t)/A = k/A * sin(w*t)
% Let k2 = k/A
k2 = k/A;
J = @(t)  k2 * sin(w*t);

% Average electron drift velocity at time t, m/s
% vd = J/n/q = I/n/q/A = k*sin(w*t)/n/q/A
% Let k3 = k/n/q/A
k3 = k/n/q/A;
vd = @(t)  k3 * sin(w*t);

% Average electron displacement at time t, m
% displacement = k/n/q/A/w * (1 - cos(w*t))
% Let k4 = k/n/q/A/w
k4 = k/n/q/A/w;
displacement = @(t)  k4 * (1 - cos(w*t));

%% Solutions
% For sin(w*t), max drift velocity occurs at w*t == pi/2 -> t = pi/2/w
vd_max = vd( pi/2/w )
    % 2.2355e-06 -> ~2.2 um/s

% Maximum average displacement of an electron during 1/2 cycle of 60 Hz 
% can be calculated as the area under the drift velocity curve during 
% the time interval (0 <= t <= pi/w) sec
% NB: For sin(w*t), 1/2 cycle occurs at w*t == pi -> t = pi/w
displacement_max = integral(vd, 0, pi/w )
    % 1.1860e-08 -> ~12 nm


%% Plot the velocity and displacement curves vs time
clf('reset')

% NB: For sin(w*t), 1/2 cycle occurs at w*t == pi -> t = pi/w
t_ = linspace( 0, pi/w );

% drift velocity in micrometers/sec at time t
vd_t = vd(t_) * 1e6;
yyaxis left
plot(t_, vd_t)

% displacement in nanometers at time t
displacement_t = displacement(t_) * 1e9;
yyaxis right
plot(t_, displacement_t)

yyaxis left
title('Velocity and Displacement vs time')
xlabel('Time (sec)')
ylabel('Velocity (um/s)')
yyaxis right
ylabel('Displacement (nm)')
grid on
```

---

[image: MATLAB plot of electron velocity and displacement vs. time]

Figure 1.   MATLAB plot of electron velocity and displacement vs. time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jim. Since no one seems to be able to get the same result as the textbook authors, unless the physics guys come up with something, I think it's likely that it is an error.

Comment: User Philip Wood from physics.stackexchange just answered that he thinks that Bruce Abbott's answer is the correct one https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/523322/141502

Comment: Jim, Phillip says that you seem to be working from a peak current, \$k\$, of \$0.1A\$, which doesn't seem to be relevant to the problem in hand.

Comment: The current value is relevant. Current is a function of voltage, and it's the electric field through the wire (caused by the potential difference across the wire) that determines the force that's applied to the electrons, and therefore the drift velocity of the electrons, and therefore the displacement of the electrons.

Comment: Phillip said the following: "The stuff in the shaded box headed "12 gauge copper.." in the page that you reproduce is about a wire that carries a constant current. It doesn't seem relevant to your question."

Comment: And for what it's worth, this solution does not take into account real world factors such as skin effect, temperature effects, and so on.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the clarification,

Comment: Jim, Phillip replied with the following: "No it isn't! I supported the use of \$x_{max}=v_{max}/\omega\$, applied to a particle moving back and forwards in a straight line with simple harmonic motion (displacement a sinusoidal function of time). This follows from the standard equation for such motion, \$x=x_{max} \sin(\omega t)\$, in which \$\omega=2\pi f\$. [If a particle is moving in a circle at a constant speed the projection of its motion on to a diameter is simple harmonic, but the simple harmonic motion itself is in a straight line!]"

Comment: My mistake. I must've misread Phillip's post.  I've deleted that comment.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So whose answer should I be viewing as the correct one? Yours or Phillip’s?

Answer (score -1):

I just saw the answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/292178/141502) by user freecharly. They claim that the mean drift velocity of electrons is $$v = \dfrac{j}{n e},$$

where

$$j = I/A$$

is the current density for current \$I\$ and cross-sectional area \$A\$, and the electron density is \$n\$. If I'm not mistaken, applying this gives us

$$\dfrac{\frac{3.02 \times 10^4 \text{A}}{\text{m}^2}}{\frac{8.5 \times 10^{28}}{\text{m}^3} \times 1.602 \times 10^{-19} \text{coulombs}} = 0.00000221781\text{m/s},$$

since \$1 \text{A} = 1 \ \frac{\text{coulomb}}{\text{s}}\$

**EDIT:** Ok, I just noticed that this calculation is for **the maximum drift velocity**, and for a **direct current cycle**, whereas what we're trying to find is the **distance between maximum swings in the drift distance for alternating current**. I seem to have confused myself and forgot precisely which result it was that I was trying to find. My apologies for any confusion caused.

Comment: That's the drift velocity for DC current, right? How does 'distance between maximum swings in the drift distance' of an AC signal relate to that?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Uhh, is it? Haha, I honestly have no idea; after all, I'm the one who asked the question. But it produces the same value, right? So either we're misunderstanding something, or the author made the incorrect calculation. Given how confusing this has been, I'm going to ask the people on physics.stackexchange for clarification on this.

Comment: I think the downvote is unreasonable. The result is the same value as that of the textbook authors'.

Comment: Perhaps someone downvoted because you didn't answer the question? (wasn't me!). Unfortunately some people do it without any explanation, even when the reason is not obvious.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Hmm, what do you mean? It seems/seemed to me that this mostly answers the question -- although, as you said, apparently this might be the calculation for electron drift for DC, rather than AC. Even so, it's a critical result in answering the question, since we were unable to make sense of this *at all* with our prior efforts, meaning that the question was probably going to be left unanswered indefinitely.

Comment: It maybe half-answers the question, but not the most important part. I couldn't explain how they got the 0.00045 mm, and I looked up the source to check that there wasn't something missing or taken out of context. But my physics knowledge is not deep so I didn't risk putting up a wrong answer. Hopefully the physics guys will be able to clarify...

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes, I have asked here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/523227/141502 . Thank you for all of your help, Bruce; I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @BruceAbbott Ok, I just noticed that this calculation is for the maximum drift velocity during an alternating current cycle, whereas what we're trying to find is the **distance between maximum swings in the drift distance for alternating current**. I seem to have confused myself and forgot precisely which result it was that I was trying to find. Now I understand what you were referring to here in the comments. My apologies for any confusion this caused!

Comment: Ok, according to Phillip Wood's answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/523322/141502, it seems that my calculation of \$0.00000221781m/s\$ is actually for direct current, which is precisely what Bruce said, and not relevant to the calculation of the distance between maximum swings in the drift distance for alternating current.

Comment: Furthermore, Phillip says "The stuff in the shaded box headed "12 gauge copper.." in the page that you reproduce is about a wire that carries a constant current. It doesn't seem relevant to your question." I wonder if perhaps this is where the authors confused themselves and made an error?